AutoARIMA Time-Series cross-validation using Sktime evaluate returns no predictions for certain folds
Data looks like this (W-SUN frequency)
**y**
2019-12-23/2019-12-29    3230
2019-12-30/2020-01-05    4347
2020-01-06/2020-01-12    4161
2020-01-13/2020-01-19    4417
2020-01-20/2020-01-26    4310

**X**  (Exogenous variables)
                        col1.  col2.    col3.   col4
date                
2019-12-23/2019-12-29   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2019-12-30/2020-01-05   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2020-01-06/2020-01-12   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2020-01-13/2020-01-19   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2020-01-20/2020-01-26   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

The code looks like below. I am using CutoffSplitter to get the different folds (see attached figure), but when AutoARIMA is fit on training data from different folds, I get no predictions for some folds.  Please note that evaluate has both y and X. Without X (Exogenous variables), I get the results for all folds using AutoARIMA, but when Exogenous variables (X) are included in evaluate, there are no predictions for first 2 folds.
forecaster = AutoARIMA(sp=52, suppress_warnings=True, n_jobs=-1) window_length=105 cutoffs = np.array([105, 131, 157]) cv = CutoffSplitter(cutoffs=cutoffs, window_length=window_length, fh=list(range(1,53)))  n_splits = cv.get_n_splits(y) print(f"Number of Folds = {n_splits}") cv_df = evaluate(forecaster=forecaster, y=y, X=X,  cv=cv, strategy="refit", return_data=True)
print(cv_df)

Expected:
Get predictions for all the folds using the evaluate as below.
print(cv_df)



test_MeanAbsolutePercentageError    fit_time    pred_time   len_train_window    cutoff  y_train y_test  y_pred
0   0.331953    0.003581    0.074185    105 2021-12-27/2022-01-02   date 2019-12-30/2020-01-05 7.355406e+05 202...  date 2022-01-03/2022-01-09 2.158099e+06 202...  2022-01-03/2022-01-09 1.609498e+06 2022-01-...
1   0.316553    0.003518    0.070260    105 2022-06-27/2022-07-03   date 2020-06-29/2020-07-05 1.197572e+06 202...  date 2022-07-04/2022-07-10 2.048764e+07 202...  2022-07-04/2022-07-10 2.159801e+06 2022-07-...
2   0.310394    0.003363    0.069245    105 2022-12-26/2023-01-01   date 2020-12-28/2021-01-03 1.567630e+06 202...  date 2023-01-02/2023-01-08 3.043255e+06 202...  2023-01-02/2023-01-08 2.158099e+06 2023-01-...

Actual:
Get predictions only for third fold.
print(cv_df)



    test_MeanAbsolutePercentageError    fit_time    pred_time   len_train_window    cutoff  y_train y_test  y_pred
0   NaN NaN **NaN** 105 NaT date 2019-12-30/2020-01-05 4.347264e+05 202...  date 2022-01-03/2022-01-09 1.095839e+06 202...  <NA>
1   NaN NaN **NaN** 105 NaT date 2020-06-29/2020-07-05 7.172772e+05 202...  date 2022-07-04/2022-07-10 1.178782e+07 202...  <NA>
2   0.303113    36.448085   0.024281    105 2022-12-26/2023-01-01   date 2020-12-28/2021-01-03 7.956712e+05 202...  date 2023-01-02/2023-01-08 1.043002e+06 202...  2023-01-02/2023-01-08 1.003961e+06 2023-01-...

